# Philosophy Articles

Tags: reference-request

Recently, I've realized that I've grown so enamored with the typical famous thinkers (Kant, Berkeley, Quine, Mill; the usual crew) that I forgot academic philosophy still exists. Unfortunately, I hardly know of any credible or quality sites to get quality contemporary news, articles, or papers on philosophy. Could any of you provide me with some suggestions?

Comment: [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](http://plato.stanford.edu/contents.html).

Comment: Presupposed an access to it, looking for relevant texts in SEP and actually getting hold of them on jstor.com would be quite a good combination.

Comment: i'd like a "new philosophy" blog to read, something just to keep up to date with whatever is being published. this could be confusion tho, on my part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://philpapers.org/
"PhilPapers is a comprehensive index and bibliography of philosophy maintained by the community of philosophers. Using advanced trawling techniques and large scale crowdsourcing, we monitor all sources of research content in philosophy, including journals, books, open access archives, and personal pages maintained by academics. We also host the largest open access archive in philosophy. "